# Заполнение массивов случайными числами

Tags: c#

Есть отдельный класс матрица, в конструкторе по умолчанию инициализируется и заполняется случайными числами двумерный массив:

```
mas = new int[3, 3];
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        mas[i, j] = rand.Next(-1, +9);
```

Проблема в том, что когда в основной программе создаю 2 объекта класса моей матрицы, оба массива получаются с одинаковыми числами.

Как сделать, что бы числа были разными?

Comment: Если поставить точку останова, при создании объектов класса, то числа уже разные... как это поправить ?

Comment: Вангую, что вы каждый раз заводите новый экземпляр класса `Random`.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то Ваша проблема описана [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Не нашел там ничего, видимо проблема в моём "французском".

Comment: В статье из MSDN гораздо больше, так что конечно стоит попробовать «осилить» её.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно ещё инициализировать Random чем-то быстро меняющимся или заведомо различным. Например:

1. `var rand = new Random((int)Stopwatch.GetTimestamp());`

`GetTimestamp()` меняется с частотой порядка нескольких МГц на современных компах, ваш же цикл выполняется несколько микросекунд. У меня за это время `GetTimestamp()` вырастает примерно на 15 тактов, т.е. seed будет разный. В общем, вряд ли найдётся такой комп, у которого `GetTimestamp()` не изменится за время заполнения массива. Разве что совсем-совсем старый какой-нибудь, у которого `Stopwatch.IsHighResolution == false`.

2. `var rand = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());`

`Guid.NewGuid()` всегда возвращает разные значения:

> To a very high degree of certainty, this function returns a unique
>   value – no other invocation, on the same or any other system
>   (networked or not), should return the same value.

(из MSDN по функции `CoCreateGuid`).

Comment: 1 вариант не прошел, ругается на Stopwatch.
2 вариант сработал

Большое спасибо)

Comment: для `Stopwatch` нужно `using System.Diagnostics;`. Вообще, хорошая штука -- позволяет измерять интервалы времени с точностью до долей микросекунды.

Comment: Пожалуйста) Но всё-таки это ad-hoc (временное решение, трюк). Правильнее, всё-таки, сделать статический экземпляр, как предложил @VladD. Если нет необходимости вызова вашего конструктора из разных потоков, то это к тому же гораздо проще. Если есть, можно заворачивать всё заполнение массива в блок `lock(rand) { ... }`.

Comment: Да, действительно, так намного проще)

Comment: На всякий случай, вот код со `static`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QNh5cR

Answer (score 5):

Дело в том, что ваша программа бежит быстро. `Random` генерирует псевдослучайные числа, высчитывая каждое новое число из предыдущего. В качестве начального значения используется текущее время. Но если ваша программа бежит быстро, то при заполнении второй матрицы начальный момент времени тот же! Ведь время «тикает» достаточно редко по сравнению с несколькими микросекундами, расходуемыми на ваш цикл. Вот и последовательность «случайных» чисел получается точно такая же.

Обычное решение этой проблемы — не пересоздавайте объект `Random`, используйте тот же самый, сохранив его в статическую переменную.

Если ваша программа многопоточная, вам придётся в каждом из потоков заводить по экземпляру `Random`, так как эти объекты не потокобезопасны. (Да, это глобальное решение локальной проблемы. Сорри.)

---

*Дополнение.* Описанная в вопросе проблема с `Random` существует лишь в .NET Framework. Если вы перейдёте на .NET Core, там матрицы будут разными, даже если вы будете создавать `Random` каждый раз в цикле.

Comment: Статик сделать мне не дает. Объект Random у меня в конструкторе по умолчанию, как я понимаю, да, у каждого нового объекта соответствующего класса свой новый объект Random. Я решил проблему, поставив задержку между созданиями объектов класса, не знаю правда, насколько это правильно)

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков: ну, положите `static` в классе, и инициализируйте его прямо на месте: `static Random rand = new Random();`.

Comment: "В качестве начального значения используется текущее время." `Environment.TickCount` (`int`, миллисекунды), точность обычно 10-16 мс.

Comment: @tsul: Угу, но это, кажется, милли-, а не микросекунды.

Comment: @VladD: Да, я и написал "милли-". Т.е. новый seed будет не менее, чем через 1 миллисекунду.

Comment: @tsul: Точно! Прошу прощения, моя невнимательность.