# Начальное значение Random() в C#

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

Подскажите, пожалуйста, на что указывает и влияет начальное значение в объявлении нового объекта Random. Допустим 999, в нашем случае.

```
Random random = new Random(999);
```

В пособии я прочитал, что объявление инициирующего значения позволяет постоянно иметь одни и те же последовательности случайных чисел при запуске метода. До конца не понял.

Comment: А что конкретно непонятно? Задаете одно и то же начальное значение - имеете одну  ту же последовательность на выходе https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @tym32167 Да, я читал эту статью на msdn, но так и не понял на что влияет установка значения , какую роль оно играет ? Чем отличается ,например Random random = new Random(); от Random random = new Random(1); или Random random = new Random(999); Там что-то со временем связано..

Comment: Разные параметры генерируют разные псевдослучайные последовательности. То есть вот пользуешься рандомом, ждешь, что он все время случайное число генерит, а нет - перезапускаешь программу а последовательность чисел такая же, как и в прошлый раз. А все потому, что создал рандом с конкретным значением (например, ваш 999). Так вот, чтобы такого не было, обычно в качестве начального значения указывают какую то случайную величину, например ```new Random(DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond);``` -  при таком раскладе получить 2 раза подряд повторяющуюся последовательность маловероятно.

Comment: @tym32167 (дополню) или что тоже самое оставляют пустым: если посмотреть в код конструктора по умолчанию -- в нём идёт вызов `: this(Environment.TickCount)`

Comment: @AK Спасибо, а то у меня буквы в комментарии кончились, не успел упомянуть :)

Comment: @tym32167 как насчет ответа? :)

Comment: @andreycha готово, скопипастил

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 30):

Одно и то же начальное значение генерирует одну ту же последовательность на выходе https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx

Другими словами, разные параметры генерируют разные псевдослучайные последовательности. То есть вот пользуешься рандомом, ждешь, что он все время случайное число генерит, а нет - перезапускаешь программу а последовательность чисел такая же, как и в прошлый раз. А все потому, что создал рандом с конкретным значением (например, ваш 999). Так вот, чтобы такого не было, обычно в качестве начального значения указывают какую то случайную величину, например

> new Random(DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond);

при таком раскладе получить 2 раза подряд повторяющуюся последовательность маловероятно.

Если посмотреть в код конструктора по умолчанию (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,52) - в нём идёт вызов

> : this(Environment.TickCount)

, то есть воспользовавшись конструктором по умолчанию, без параметров, с большой долей вероятности каждый раз будут генерироваться разные псевдослучайные последовательности.

Именно проблема инициализации класса Random часто приводит к вопросам новичков. Как я писал выше, по умолчанию Random создается с параметром Environment.TickCount. Таким образом, если создать 2 класса Random подряд, то они скорее всего будут инициализированы одним и тем же значением, и, как следствие, будут генерировать одну и ту же последовательность.

Проверить это легко:

```
// Смотрим, что можно получить одинаковый TickCount, 
// если запросить его 2 раза подряд
var test1 = Environment.TickCount;
var test2 = Environment.TickCount;

Console.WriteLine($"test1: {test1}");
Console.WriteLine($"test2: {test2}");

// Создаем 2 рандома подряд. Так как интервал времени 
// между созданием экземпляров небольшой, 
// скорее всего они будут инициализировны одним и тем же TickCount 
// и будут генерировать одну и ту же последовательность превдослучайных чисел
var r1 = new Random();
var r2 = new Random();

Console.WriteLine($"random1: {r1.Next()}");
Console.WriteLine($"random2: {r2.Next()}");
```

Вывод примера в консоль:

```
test1: 570009681
test2: 570009681
random1: 888018196
random2: 888018196
```

Как видно, были сгенерированы одни и те же случайные числа для рандомов, созданных в одно и то же время. Непонимание этой особенности обычно порождает вопросы у начинающих программистов. Как примеры:

На русском:

[random заполняет две матрицы одинаковыми значениями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575638/random-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)

[C# случайные числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/234407/c-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0/234410)

[Заполнение массивов случайными числами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498127/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/498139)

на английском

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number

Comment: Нужно дописать, что именно это приводит к очень частому вопросу новичков - одинаковые 'случайные' числа, когда ГСЧ инициализируется одним и тем же значением. И дать ссылку на подобный вопрос, их тут достаточно. Я сейчас с телефона, неудобно писать, может потом сам поправлю.

Comment: @AK проапдейтил. Если хочется что то поправить - велком

Comment: Кажется, скоро вы получите первый знак "хороший ответ", с почином!

Comment: @AK Уже получил, спасибо :)

Comment: Стоит добавить, чтобы два подряд созданных `Random` выдавали разные последовательности, надо создавать их так: `new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())`

Comment: @Андрей по идее, не совсем понятно, зачем нужно было бы создавать 2 рандома подряд :) МС вообще рекомендует делать один рандом на все приложение https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx#ThreadSafety

Comment: @tym32167, почитайте комментарии к этому вопросу, например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/677728/218063

Comment: @Андрей почитал, имхо, Random.GetBytes должно было решить проблему https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357760/how-can-i-generate-a-random-biginteger-within-a-certain-range

Comment: Вопрос был про явное указание seed, а большая часть ответа почему-то - про конструктор без параметров...

Comment: @PavelMayorov я всего лишь упомянул, что конструктор без параметров также задает seed - это не большая часть ответа, к тому же напрямую относится к вопросу