# Как формируется значение в Random? Как предугадать последующие?

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

Как формируется случайное значение в обьекте Random? Каков механизм, можно ли предугадать каждое последующее значение Random ?

Comment: Вот веселое видео на тему рандома в c#. https://youtu.be/eLw-gRofeGo

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Начальное значение Random() в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687355/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-random-%d0%b2-c)

Comment: @Flippy датчики? Можете указать в какой версии .NET там датчики, и дать ссылку на соответствующие сорцы?

Comment: @Сергей исходники, вроде, у ,NET открыты и там можно посмотреть как оно реализовано. Угадывание следующих значений сделать реально, но нужно знать реализацию генератора.

Comment: @Flippy я наверняка уверен что не датчики ;-)

Comment: @Flippy учитывая что это про разные языки - совсем НЕ такой вопрос.

Comment: @Flippy это неверно. В различных языках в стандартной библиотеке разная реализация рандома.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, тогда хз))

Comment: @Nikita какие-то индусы в комментариях под тем видео собрались...