# Генерация случайных цифр в матрице. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть матрица состоящая из TextBlock'ов. Когда я нажимаю на кнопку "Сгенерировать числа" то генерируются все одинаковые числа. Я же хочу сгенерировать все случайные числа. Не пойму, где сделал ошибку.

Код XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Lab_2_part_2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Lab_2_part_2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>

        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Label Content="Ввод матрицы" FontSize="25"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" >
                <Label Content="Количество строк" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox Text="4" IsReadOnly="True" Name ="Rows" Margin="5" Width="100" />
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                <Label Content="Количество столбцов" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox Text="4" IsReadOnly ="True" Name="Columns" Margin="5" Width="100"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid >

        <Grid Name="MatrixGrid" MinHeight="100" Margin="100 10 100 10">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Name="zero_zero" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontStretch="Expanded"/>
            <TextBlock Name="one_zero" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <TextBlock Name="two_zero" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <TextBlock Name="three_zero" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"/>

            <TextBlock Name="zero_one" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <TextBlock Name="one_one" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <TextBlock Name="two_one" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <TextBlock Name="three_one" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"/>

            <TextBlock Name="zero_two" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <TextBlock Name="one_two" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <TextBlock Name="two_two" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <TextBlock Name="three_two" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2"/>

            <TextBlock Name="zero_three" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"/>
            <TextBlock Name="one_three" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"/>
            <TextBlock Name="two_three" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"/>
            <TextBlock Name="three_three" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3"/>

        </Grid>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Margin="5 0 5 0" Grid.Column ="0" Content="Сгенерировать числа" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Margin="5 0 5 0" Grid.Column ="1" Content="Заменить еденицы нулями"/>

        </Grid>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Код Window.xaml.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WPF_Lab_2_part_2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        List<TextBlock> matrx;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            matrx = new List<TextBlock>();
            FillMatrix();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                foreach(TextBlock a in matrx)
                {
                    a.Text = new Random().Next(0, 10).ToString();
                }
            }



        }

        private void FillMatrix()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    TextBlock temp = (TextBlock)GetChildren(MatrixGrid, i, j);
                    matrx.Add(temp);
                }
            }
        }

        private static UIElement GetChildren(Grid grid, int row, int column)
        {
            foreach (UIElement child in grid.Children)
            {
                if (Grid.GetRow(child) == row
                      &&
                   Grid.GetColumn(child) == column)
                {
                    return child;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется вы используете плохой способ для отображения матрицы. Возможно вам лучше использовать [DataGrid2D](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в строчке

```
a.Text = new Random().Next(0, 10).ToString();
```

Сделайте ваш экземпляр `Random` статическим:

```
static Random random = new Random();
```

и пользуйтесь только им:

```
a.Text = random.Next(0, 10).ToString();
```

---

*Пояснение.*

Класс `Random` представляет собой генератор псевдослучайных чисел, в котором каждое следующее число вычисляется из предыдущего. При создании класса через `new Random()` он инициализирует начальное значение из текущего времени.

Если вы в каждой итерации цикла создаёте новый `Random()`, то это происходит практически одновременно, и отметка времени не успевает поменяться! Таким образом, значение, вычисляемое в `Next(0, 10)`, всё время одно и то же, потому что оно получается из одного и того же начального значения.

Comment: Спасибо! Раз уж это зависит от времени, то в каждой итерации я попробую поставить Thread.Sleep(100). Посмотрим, работает или нет. Интересно же)

Comment: @НазарМазурик: Да, должно сработать :) Но UI будет подвисать.

Comment: @НазарМазурик был уже как то подобный [вопрос про рандом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687355/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-random-%D0%B2-c/687368#687368)

Comment: @tym32167: Надо бы кому-нибудь не полениться, написать канонический вопросоответ, и закрывать остальные как дубли.

Comment: @VladD я то только за, вопрос кто бы это сделал :)