# Создание экземпляра класса в лямбда выражении

Tags: c#, .net

Здравстуйте! Была элементарная задача, перемешать массив и выбрать Х элементов из этого массива. 
Написал так:

```
int[] result = sourceArray.OrderBy(x=>new Random().Next()).Take(X).ToArray();
```

Но возвращаемый массив не перемешался, т.е. метод Next() вернул одно значение для всех итераций.

```
Random random = new Random();

int[] result = sourceArray.OrderBy(x=>random.Next()).Take(X).ToArray();
```

Так работает.

Насколько я понимаю, это все из-за замыкания. Так ли это? Может кто-нибудь поподробнее растолковать что тут происходит? Спасибо!

Comment: `.OrderBy(x=>new System().Next())` какая то бессмысленная конструкция

Comment: Прощу прощения. Исправил.

Comment: Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь [вот с этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687355/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-random-%D0%B2-c/687368#687368)

Comment: Да, все понял, все проще чем я думал...