# Разный результат программы при отладке

Tags: c#, отладка

Есть код :

```
for(int j = 0; j < 2000; j++)
            {
                Tuple<List<sbyte>, List<Tuple<string, double>>> Cond = Strategies.Strategies.SmaStrategy(Bars, TF, null);
                CalcCondition(Bars, Cond, false, false);
            }
```

Не суть всего описания. `Cond` у меня всегда разный т.к. в функции `SmaStrategy` значения вычисляются рандомно. В `CalcCondition` я при разном условии `Cond.Item1` прибавляю или убавляю какое-то значение. Результат в итоге добавляю в список. Потом распечатываю этот список, там 2000 значений. Если я просто запускаю программу, у меня почему-то повторяются значения по 3-4 раза. Если через отладку медленно проверяю значения, которые заношу в список, они там не повторяются и всё отлично. Как может быть такая разница?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2 картинки различаются только тем, что в первой я просто запустил программу и она просчитала, а во втором, я поставил `breakpoint` на место добавления результата в список и через `Shift+F11` прогонял по очереди, поэтому там нету совпадений

Comment: Наверное, потому что вы зачем-то производите в цикле переинициализацию ГПСЧ текущим временем.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов да, вы правы. Сталкивался с этим когда-то давно, поэтому не особо следил за таким моментом. Спасибо большое

Comment: Скорее всего [проблема в этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687355/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-random-%D0%B2-c/687368#687368)

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, я прочитаю