# Как починить рандом?

Tags: c#, консоль

Ниже описан метод для создания бинарного дерева. В нем сломался рандом: постоянно выводится одно и тоже число. Посоветуйте, как решить данную проблему?

P.S. Кто-то посчитал этот вопрос дубликатом [Начальное значение Random() в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687355/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-random-%D0%B2-c), но это не так. В том случае человек задавал одно и тоже начальное значение, у меня же оно отсутствует. Насколько я понял в этом случае рандом использует время, как отправную точку, но даже тогда он не должен постоянно генерировать одно и тоже число, для нескольких переменных при одновременном запуске.

P.P.S. Рандом работает нормально при использовании из main.

```
static Tree IdealTree(int size, Tree p)
    {
        int info = 0;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        info = rnd.Next(0, 100);
        Tree r;        
        int nl, nr;
        if (size == 0)
        {
            p = null; return p;
        }
        nl = size / 2;
        nr = size - nl - 1;
        int d = info;
        r = new Tree(d);
        r.left = IdealTree(nl, r.left);
        r.right = IdealTree(nr, r.right);
        p = r;
        return p;
    }
```

Comment: Этих вопросов про Random масса и приведённый ответ --  эталонная закрывашка. В нём есть упоминание про то, что если два раза быстро создать два экземпляра, то начальные значения совпадут. Почитайте внимательно этот вопрос и другие -- это реально одна и та ситуация воспроизводится.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё дело в том что Random при инициализации конструктора без параметров инициализируется в зависимости от текущего времени, если сделать сразу несколько запросов подряд, то за это время время не изменяется и Random генерирует одинаковые значения.

Сам Random при инициализации одинаковым числом генерирует одну и туже последовательность. В вашей функции он каждый раз инициализируется заново и как раз одинаковым параметром.

Решение: Вынести переменную Random за пределы функции, и передавать в функцию как параметр.

```
Random r1 = new Random();
var a1 = r1.Next();
r1 = new Random();
var a2 = r1.Next();
```

Высока вероятность что a1 == a2 == a3 итп.

```
Random r1 = new Random();

var a1 = r1.Next();
var a2 = r1.Next();
var a3 = r1.Next();
```

a1, a2, a3 - разные числа, если случайно не совпадут.

Answer (score 1):

Все «внутренности» работы класса Random полностью детерминистичны. Это значит, что если вы возьмёте несколько экземпляров класса Random с одинаковым начальным состоянием, которое задаётся через параметр конструктора seed, и для каждого экземпляра вызовите определённые методы в одинаковом порядке и с одинаковыми параметрами, то в конце вы получите одинаковые результаты.

Как починить, и статья раскрывающая тему по ссылке
https://habrahabr.ru/post/165459/

З.Ы.Ж. Простейший вариант заплатки:

```
Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
```