# создание new Random() - утечка памяти?

Tags: c#, .net

нужно написать генератор произвольных символов

```
public char CharGenerator()
{
Random rnd = new Random();
return (char)('a' + rnd.Next(26));
}
```

метод нужен для генерации строки => будет вызываться часто
не совсем понятно: будет ли частое создание нового рандома вызывать утечки памяти?
как лучше передавать уже созданный экземпляр?

Comment: Стоит использовать общий экземпляр, но не из-за утечек памяти (в C# есть сборщик мусора), а из-за того, что созданные подряд экземпляры `Random` произведут одинаковые последовательности случайных чисел.

Comment: @VladD очень хороший совет, забыл про такое поведение

Comment: Не буду дубликатить, просто упомяну для создания связи между вопросами: [Начальное значение Random() в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/687355/213987)

Comment: @VladD [эмм...](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,52)

Comment: @andreycha: Ну да. Если создавать подряд, то `Tick` будет один и тот же.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так переделать

```
public class CharGenerator {
    private Random rnd = new Random();

    public char Generate()
    {
        return (char)('a' + rnd.Next(26));
    }
}
```