# Исключение типа StackOverflow C#

Tags: c#, исключения

В строке определения переменной text возникает ошибка `StackOverflow` и не знаю как можно избавиться от его потому что условие обязательное.

```
private string MakeExpresion()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        char operation = (r.Next(0, 2) == 0) ? '+' : '-';
        int num1 = r.Next(1, 51);
        int num2 = r.Next(1, 51);
        string text = (num1 > num2) ? $"{num1} {operation} {num2}" : MakeExpresion();
        return text;
    }
```

Comment: Лично у меня все отработало спокойно

Comment: @LiptonDev, потому что вам повезло, прогоните программу несколько раз и столкнетесь с данной проблемой

Comment: У вас длина рекурсии вычисляется случайным образом. Не знаю, зачем вы это делаете, но надеюсь просто по фану так пишете, а не в прод

Comment: почему бы если `num1 < num2`, не поменять бы их местами, чтобы избавиться от рекурсивного вызова?

Comment: а как можно получить выражение с первым большим числом и без появления таких ошибок

Comment: использовать метод Swap?

Comment: Именно, swap поможет, то, что вы делаете - неправильно

Comment: Хм. А можно ли объяснить причину появление данного исключения в ответ?

Comment: Если кратко - вы создаете инстанс System.Random с одинаковым seed`ом. Это вкупе с "удачным" рандомным числом приводит к бесконечной рекурсии.

Comment: Кратно для меня не есть понятно. Вы уж извините...

Comment: Сейчас распишу ответ, ждите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы же получаете числа случайным образом, верно? Допустим, что вам выпал num1<=num2. Это может случиться? Вполне. Так как класс Random у вас создается при каждом запуске, то, скорее всего, между 2 рекурсивными вызовами проходит мало времени и второй рандом создается с [тем же начальным значением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687355/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-random-%D0%B2-c/687368#687368), что и первый, и, как следствие, генерирует те же самые случайные числа, что и в прошлый раз. И снова вы входите в рекурсию. Так продолжается, пока не произойдет переполнение стека и программа не упадет.

Без рекурсии

```
private string MakeExpresion()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    char operation = (r.Next(0, 2) == 0) ? '+' : '-';
    int num1 = r.Next(1, 51);
    int num2 = r.Next(1, 51);

    while(num2 == num1) num2 = r.Next(1, 51);
    if (num1 < num2) {
        var tmp = num1;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = tmp;
    }

    string text = $"{num1} {operation} {num2}";
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Буду благодарен за подробности возникновения данного исключения в моем методе. Наперед говорю спасибо!

Comment: @SeeSharp добавил

Comment: То есть, когда я создаю новый экземпляр класса то значение не изменяется и так пока стек не переполнится. А что означает данное выражение: переполнить стек??

Comment: @SeeSharp Если объекты класса Random создаете примерно в одно и то же время, то такие объекты будут генерировать одинаковые "случайные" числа. Подробнее смотрите по ссылке что я дал в ответе.

Comment: @SeeSharp Есть такое место в памяти - называется стек. Помимо прочего, он там хранит ссылки на параметры, локаьные переменные метода и прочее. То есть каждый раз, когда вы вызываете метод, то в этот стек добавляется некоторая информация. Каждый раз, когда метод заканчивает выполнение - эта информация оттуда удаляется. При рекурсивном вызове методов, вы много-много раз вызываете метод, то есть информация в стек добавляется много-много раз, пока он не переполнится, что приводит к вашей ситуации.

Comment: Вот теперь полностью разобрался с моей проблемой и понял что делать. Спасибо Вам и Вашему коллеге за ответ.

Comment: @SeeSharp пожалуйста. рад, что заработало как надо

Answer (score 7):

Вся проблема в том, что нельзя создавать объекты класса Random в циклах или рекурсиях. Почему? Потому что для seed`а используются системные часы:

> Начальное значение по умолчанию извлекается из системных часов и
>   конечности разрешающей. В результате разные Random объекты,
>   создаваемые в закрытой последовательности путем вызова конструктора по
>   умолчанию будет иметь одинаковые начальное значение по умолчанию и,
>   таким образом, будут производить идентичные наборы случайных чисел.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx

Если самый первый рандом выдаст числа num1 < num2, seed при следующем создании System.Random вряд ли успеет смениться, а если и успеет, есть вероятность, что Random.Next опять выдаст num1 < num2 и весь цикл повторится.

---

Если уж и использовать Random, то один на "метод":

```
private string MakeExpression()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return MakeExpressionInternal(rnd);
    }

private string MakeExpresionInternal(Random rnd)
    {           
        char operation = (rnd.Next(0, 2) == 0) ? '+' : '-';
        int num1 = rnd.Next(1, 51);
        int num2 = rnd.Next(1, 51);
        string text = (num1 > num2) ? $"{num1} {operation} {num2}" : MakeExpresionInternal(rnd);
        return text;
    }
```

Скажу сразу - есть вероятность, что Random будет выдавать числа num1 < num2, пока не упадет стэк, тут уже дело в том, что Random будет выдавать такие числа, это никак не предугадать/исправить. Поэтому рекурсию, зависящую от рандома, не стоит делать.

---

Как вам уже подсказали, использовать рекурсию здесь, мягко говоря, плохо. Все данные уже сгенерированы, вопрос только в том, какое число их них больше, почему бы просто их не поменять местами, чем заново генерировать значения?

Comment: Сорри, что отнял ваши баллы. Поздно увидел, что вы тоже ответили. Ловите от меня хотя бы плюсик. Спасибо за старание :)

Comment: Да не за что извиняться, будто бы баллы - первое, ради чего мы все здесь сидим. Главное, что проблему решили, да и ваш ответ содержит правильно написанную программу, помимо объяснения проблемы :)

Comment: Можно и рекурсиях рэндом делать, но между итерациями вставлять искусственную задержку. У автора проблема даже не в том, что он генерирует рэндомы в рекурсии, а в том, что он их генерирует сразу же друг за другом, не выдержав никакого интервала. Даже если убрать рекурсию - ошибка переполнения, конечно, уйдет, но - код сравнения рэндомов не будет иметь смысла

Comment: @Александр Вы предлагаете намеренно уменьшать быстродействие программы вместо создания одного экземпляра System.Random? :)

Comment: @Александр, я расписал обе ошибки: ошибка создания System.Random с одинаковым seed`ом и проблема с рекурсией. Начнем с того, что автору совершенно не нужна рекурсия с его задачей, а закончим тем, что такая рекурсия с какой-то вероятностью положит вашу программу, а это явно не то, чего вы хотите.

Comment: А с random и нет других вариантов, если необходимо прогонять в цикле. Если без задержек, тогда RNGCryptoServiceProvider использовать. Грамотная рекурсия программу не положит.

Comment: Зачем нам изначально создавать несколько объектов Random`а? Ладно бы мы в нескольких потоках этим занимались, но в данном случае для чего для каждой генерации создавать новый Random? "Грамотная рекурсия" это какая? Конкретно здесь продолжение рекурсии напрямую зависит от рандома, есть вероятность того, что рекурсия будет продолжаться до тех пор, пока не кончится стэк. Да, вероятность такого события невероятно мала, но тем не менее она есть. Тогда какой смысл в данном случае выдумывать велосипед, а потом пытаться его починить, если проблема в самой логике алгоритма?