# Исключения в Random.Range()

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать чтобы при генерации Random.Range(2, 15)
сделать чтобы числа 5 и 11 не могли сгенерироваться то есть только числа

2 3 4 6 7 8 9 10 12 13 14 15 могли сгенриться!

Comment: Заведите массив с допустимыми значениями и генерируйте индекс к нему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Универсальный код для шарпа:

```
var _rand = new System.Random();//вообще эту штуку лучше вывести ЗА метод и не плодить инстансы этого класса внутри методов

private int RandomFromRangeWithExceptions(int rangeMin, int rangeMax, params int[] exclude)//exclude -- список чисел которые НЕ должны входить в результат
{
    var range = Enumerable.Range(rangeMin, rangeMax).Where(i => !exclude.Contains(i));//создаем  колекцию допустимых значений

    int index = _rand.Next(rangeMin, rangeMax - exclude.Count);//генерируем индекс ячейки
    return range.ElementAt(index);//возвращаем значение ячейки
}
```

Код оптимизированный под юнити:

```
private int RandomFromRangeWithExceptions(int rangeMin, int rangeMax, params int[] exclude)//exclude -- список чисел которые НЕ должны входить в результат
{
    var range = Enumerable.Range(rangeMin, rangeMax).Where(i => !exclude.Contains(i));//создаем  колекцию допустимых значений
    int index = Random.Range(rangeMin, rangeMax - exclude.Count);//генерируем индекс ячейки
    return range.ElementAt(index);//возвращаем значение ячейки
}
```

пример вызова:

```
RandomFromRangeWithExceptions(2, 15,   5, 11);
```

или

```
RandomFromRangeWithExceptions(1, 100,  5, 11, 14, 2, 99, 48);
```

Код базируется на этом ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18485399/4423545

Код изменялся и не проверялся на наличие ошибок, но все должно пахать.

PS: Для удобства использования можно замутить этот метод как расширение к классу Random в случае Юнити.

Comment: Создание перечисления на каждый вызов кажется не очень эффективным решением. Плюс создание `Random` на каждый вызов может [подпортить генерацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/687368/179763)

Comment: вопрос касался в первую очередь юнити, так что если использовать метод заточенный под юнити -- он не создает свой рандом и проблем с генерацией не возникнет. Но если учесть что я написал сначала код для шарпа в общем -- то да, согласен. Что до создания перечисления.... А есть решение лучше?)

Comment: ну, если говорить о решении лучше - то я бы создал массив допустимых значений один раз и переиспользовал бы его (как параметр метода - метод с генерацией не должен создавать какие то массивы или решать, что включено, а что исключено) + класс Random я бы также создавал 1 раз либо в статическое поле (но надо иметь ввиду, что этот класс не является потокобезоасным), либо передавал бы его как параметр метода или параметр конструктора класса с этим методом.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо за критику, принял информацию к сведенью) Но переписывать код выше не стану :)

Comment: да без проблем, ваше право :)

Comment: @Andrew А с Float значениями работает?

Comment: нет конечно, под флоат нужно отдельный метод писать.

Comment: А для Float можно пример?

Comment: Нельзя. Вопрос касался интов. На флоаты заводи другой вопрос. Что б с флоатами было то же самое -- раздели рандомное число на целую и дробную части. Целая -- твой индекс. Дробная -- дробь которую нужно добавить к значению вытягнутому по индексу.