# Создание приложения, генерирующего гистограмму: не читаются значения из файла

Tags: c#, файлы, генерация-случайных-данных, гистограммы, графики

Задача всё та же. Пишу приложение, которое будет строить столбчатую гистограмму с рандомными цветами столбцов, значения столбцов рандомные. Всё бы хорошо, но предварительно мне нужно нажать кнопку, которая сгенерирует значения и запишет их в файл. Вторая кнопка отвечает за чтение значений из файла и выводит значения (высоту столбцов) в виде цветных разноцветных столбцов. Код прилагаю ниже. **Проблем** две: при нажатии "Записать" значения в файл не записываются, приложение на нажатия не реагирует. При нажатии "Прочитать" просто ничего не происходит (логично, ведь значения считать не получается). В какую сторону мне копать? Синтаксических ошибок компилятор не видит. С логикой запутался и в упор ошибку не вижу.

```
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()

    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    Pen coord = new Pen(Color.Black);
    public List<int> massive = new List<int> ();
    public Random rnd = new Random();
    int size;
    int width;

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) //Рисуем оси
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        size = rnd.Next(1, 10);
        width = 700 / 2/ size;
        g.TranslateTransform(50, 213);
        g.DrawLine(coord, 0, -200, 0, 200); //Y axis (ось)
        g.DrawLine(coord, 0, 0, 700, 0); //X axis (ось)


    }

    public void write_all() //Записываем значения в файл 
    {
        int w = 0;
        string data = null;
        Random wrd = new Random();
        for (int b = 1; b < 10;)
        {
            w = wrd.Next(5, 120);
            data = data + Convert.ToString(w) + "\r";
        }
        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\test\graphs.txt", new string[] { data });
    }


        private void draw_all (List<int> massive) //Рисуем столбцы, прочитав значения из ранее созданного файла
    {
        Pen rec = new Pen (Color.Black);
        Random rclr = new Random();
        SolidBrush filler = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(rclr.Next(0, 256), rclr.Next(0, 256), rclr.Next(0, 256)));
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        g.TranslateTransform(0, 213);
        int x = 0;
        Random graphs = new Random();
        int visota = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 10;)
        {
            string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines((@"C:\test\graphs.txt"));
            foreach (string w in readText)   
            {
                visota = Convert.ToInt32 (w); 
            }
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, 0 - visota, 30, visota);
            g.FillRectangle(filler, rect);
            filler.Color = Color.FromArgb(rclr.Next(0, 256), rclr.Next(0, 256), rclr.Next(0, 256));
            x = x + 80;
            i++;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Вывод на форму (Кнопка прочитать)
    {
        Refresh();
        draw_all(massive);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Запись значений и создание файла со значениями
    {
        write_all();
    }
}
```

Comment: `string data = string.Empty;`

Comment: По-прежнему не пишутся значения в файл, после нажатия кнопки приложение не реагирует ни на что

Comment: `for (int b = 1; b < 10;)` что это за цикл такой? b++ потеряли?

Comment: И правда. Как-то невнимательно цикл писал. Спасибо. Теперь работает, но получаю другую ошибку: строка visota = Convert.ToInt32 (w); "Входная строка имела неверный формат"

Comment: Ну a чему равно это `w`?

Comment: Значению, которое читается из файла, который теперь благополучно создается и хранит значения

Comment: конкретно в момент когда ошибка происходит, чему равно значение этой переменной?

Comment: Сейчас ещё раз просмотрел значения. Их нет. Просто " "  вместо числа и всё. Но файл изменяется и хранит сгенерированные значения.

Comment: Проблема в переносах между строкой. Удалил + "\r" , получил очень большое число. Естественно его вывести нельзя. Осталось научить программу читать всё и понимать, где новое значение. С этим у меня уже проблемы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поглядим на вашу функцию:

```
public void write_all() //Записываем значения в файл 
{
    int w = 0;
    string data = null;
    Random wrd = new Random();
    for (int b = 1; b < 10;)
    {
        w = wrd.Next(5, 120);
        data = data + Convert.ToString(w) + "\r";
    }
    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\test\graphs.txt", new string[] { data });
}
```

Проблема 1)

```
for (int b = 1; b < 10;)
```

В этом цикле нет выхода. Думаю, вы хотели написать вот так

```
for (int b = 1; b < 10; b++)
```

Проблема 2)

Вы добавляете `"\r"` видимо в качестве символа переноса строки. Но это не является переносом строки. Перенос строки - это `Environment.NewLine`. То есть

```
        data = data + Convert.ToString(w) + Environment.NewLine;
```

Проблема 3)

Вы пишете в переменную `data` многострочный текст, то есть храните несколько строк в одной. Непонятно, зачем все эти сложности. Вот так будет гораздо проще

```
// не надо создавать ГПСЧ каждый раз, подробнее тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/687368/179763
Random wrd = new Random(); 
public void write_all() //Записываем значения в файл 
{   
    var lines = new List<string>(); // сюда сложим все строки, что будем писать в файл
    for (int b = 1; b < 10; b++)
    {       
        // wrd.Next(5, 120) генерирует число, чтобы превратить его в строку, вызываем .ToString()
        lines.Add(wrd.Next(5, 120).ToString());             
    }
    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\test\graphs.txt", lines);
}
```

Можно пойти ещё дальше, и использовать Linq, тогда вся функция будет одной строкой

```
Random wrd = new Random();
public void write_all() //Записываем значения в файл 
{   
    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\test\graphs.txt", 
        Enumerable.Range(1, 9)
            .Select(x=>wrd.Next(5, 120).ToString())
            .ToArray());
}
```

Разбор Linq я делать не буду, это выходит за рамки вопроса - пусть это будет вашим домашним заданием.

Comment: Всё предельно понятно. Огромное спасибо за такой развёрнутый ответ!

Comment: @nvmqa пожалуйста