# Заполнение двумерного массива случайными значениями

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

Я создаю двумерный массив размеров 6x6 (6 столбцов и 6 рядов). Заполняю его "+", а затем с помощью Random.Next расставляю 2 символа "@". Код работает, всё прекрасно за исключением одного момента: c б**о**льшой вероятностью "собачки" появляются вместе, т.е если первый символ имеет индекс [2, 3] то второй имеет [2, 4].

Увеличение значения a, отвечающего за кол-во "собачек", так же ни к чему не приводит - символы всё так же появляются последовательно друг за другом.

В чём может быть причина? Я пришёл к выводу, что это точно связано с генерацией случайных значений, но как это влияет на работу программы - непонятно.

```cs
using System;

namespace Project
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[,] map = new string[6, 6];
            MapBuilder map_builder = new MapBuilder();
            map = map_builder.Generate(map);

            int rows = map.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
            int columns = map.Length / rows;
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{map[i, j]} \t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class MapBuilder
    {
        public string[,] Generate(string[,] map)
        {
            int height = map.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
            int width = map.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                {
                    map[i, j] = "+";
                }
            }


            int a = 4;
            while (0 < a)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                    {
                        if ((Percent(1, 101) <= 5) && (map[i, j] != "@") && (0 < a) && (i != 0) && (i != (height - 1)) && (j != 0) && (j != (width - 1)))
                        {
                            map[i, j] = "@";
                            a = a - 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return map;
        }

        private int Percent(int min, int max)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            return rnd.Next(min, max);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

О, этот избитый вопрос про [инициализацию рандома](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687355/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-random-%d0%b2-c)! Поставил инициализацию рандома в конструкторе класса - всё сразу случайно генерится.

```
void Main()
{
    string[,] map = new string[6, 6];
    MapBuilder map_builder = new MapBuilder();
    map = map_builder.Generate(map);

    int rows = map.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
    int columns = map.Length / rows;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{map[i, j]} \t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

}

// Define other methods and classes here
class MapBuilder
{
    public MapBuilder()
    {
        this.Rnd = new Random();
    }

    public string[,] Generate(string[,] map)
    {
        int height = map.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
        int width = map.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                map[i, j] = "+";
            }
        }


        int a = 4;
        while (0 < a)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                {
                    if ((Percent(1, 101) <= 5) && (map[i, j] != "@") && (0 < a) && (i != 0) && (i != (height - 1)) && (j != 0) && (j != (width - 1)))
                    {
                        map[i, j] = "@";
                        a = a - 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    private int Percent(int min, int max)
    {
        return this.Rnd.Next(min, max);
    }

    private Random Rnd {get; set; }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]