# Убрать повторяющиеся значения

Tags: c#

В данном куске кода должно выводить текст с рандомным числом - это он выполняет.

```
public void FreePlace()
        {
            var rnd = new Random();
            rnd.Next(1, 5);
            int fp = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < rnd.Next(1, 5); i++) {
                fp = rnd.Next(1, 5);

                Console.WriteLine($"Свободно место: №{fp}");
            }
        }
```

Единственное что не могу понять - как сделать, чтобы не выводились повторные значения.
Например, вот: выводятся дважды строки ***"Свободное место: #2"***.

Предполагаю, что требуется что-то подобное Distinct()?

[image]

Comment: Distinct применяется к коллекции, а в данном случае коллекции нет.

Comment: Напишите что должен делать этот код. Не совсем ясно чего Вы пытаетесь добиться вызывая `rnd.Next(1, 5);` впустую.

Comment: Если вам нужны неповторяющиеся числа, то создайте ряд чисел и перемешайте его. Только не спрашивайте как - куча ответов уже была.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте это

```
var rnd = new Random();
foreach (var fp in Enumerable.Range(1, 5).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()))
    Console.WriteLine($"Свободно место: №{fp}");
```

И не забудьте, что `Random` лучше созать [один раз и переиспользовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/687368/179763).

Вывод

```
Свободно место: №4
Свободно место: №3
Свободно место: №5
Свободно место: №2
Свободно место: №1
```

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы выводилось, например не ровно 5 свободных мест, а каждый раз число свободных мест варьировалось от 1 до 5? Т.е , чтобы было рандомное количество свободных мест

Comment: Замените 5 в моем ответе на случайное число. Как получать случайные числа есть в вашем вопросе.