# Random - размеры окна chromedriver

Tags: c#

Почему у браузера не открываются окна рандомных размеров ?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Random random = new Random();
    List<string> textList = new List<string>() 
    {
        "q",
        "w",
        "e",
        "r",
        "t",
        "y",
        "u",
        "i",
        "o",
        "p"
    };

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ZapuskPotokov(30);
    }

    private void ZapuskPotokov(int viborKolPotokov)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < viborKolPotokov; i++)
        {
            int j = i;
            Task.Run(() => Algoritm(j, viborKolPotokov));
        }
    }

    private void Algoritm(int num1, int num2)
    {
        //Debug.WriteLine(random.Next(0, 10).ToString());
        //Debug.WriteLine(textList[random.Next(0, 10)]);
        //Debug.WriteLine($"текст {random.Next(0, 10)} текст");
        ZapuskBrauzera();
    }

    private void ZapuskBrauzera()
    {

        IWebDriver Browser;

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        options.AddArgument($"--window-size={random.Next(400, 1800)}, {random.Next(400, 980)}");


        var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        //driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

        Browser = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));

    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687355/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-random-%d0%b2-c

Comment: @AK дак вон цифры, буквы из листа рандомные, а вот окна все одинаковые

Comment: Ну, [код настройки](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23381324/5752652) размеров окна правильный - поэтому мне и показалось что с цифрами что-то неладно. А первая ошибка с рандомом какая? Что начальное значение рандома одинаковое.

Answer (score -1):

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"--window-size={random.Next(400, 1800)}, {random.Next(400, 980)}";
process.Start();
```

Если и это не поможет, значит ошибка в аргументах. Вероятно всего, неверный формат.