# Почти всегда 1-й и 2-й массивы выводятся одинаковые( и их минимумы тоже). Не могу понять, почему так происходит

Tags: c#, массивы, случайные-числа

```
public int min_elem(params int[] el)
        {
            int min = el[0];
            foreach (int i in el)
            {
                if (i < min)
                    min = i;
            }
            return min;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            int[] mass = new int[n];
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                mass[i] = r.Next(30);
                textBox2.Text += mass[i].ToString() + " ,";//выводим 1-й массив по одному элементу
            }
            textBox3.Text += min_elem(mass).ToString();//выводим минимум 1-го массива
            
            int[] mass1 = new int[n];
            Random r1 = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                mass1[i] = r1.Next(30);
                textBox4.Text += mass1[i].ToString() + " ,";//выводим 2-й массив по одному элементу
            }
            textBox5.Text += min_elem(mass1).ToString();//выводим минимум 2-го массива
        }
```

Comment: Версия дотнета какая? Используйте свежую, там нет этой проблемы.

Comment: Этот вопрос задавался сотню раз ([например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/687368/220553)), стоит закрыть дубликатом, а в дубликате дописать текущие реалии (что исправлено в .NET и лучше использовать `Random.Shared`).

Answer (score 0):

Создавайте рандом генератор один раз и дальше используйте один и тот же генератор во всём коде.

```
Random r = new Random();
...
mass1[i] = r.Next(30)
...
mass2[i] = r.Next(30)
```

Генератор случайных чисел по умолчанию инициализируется с использованием текущего времени. Поэтому если вы подряд в коде инициализируете несколько генераторов, все эти генераторы скорее всего будут выдавать одну и ту же последовательность чисел.

Так что либо использовать один генератор для всех случайных чисел. Либо инициализировать генераторы чем-то действительно случайным (или хотя бы разными числами, инкрементируя их).

Comment: Или использовать [Random.Shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.shared?view=net-8.0)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov .NET 6, 7, 8 - не удивительно, что я не знал )  Но хорошо, что теперь такое есть.

Comment: В Framework 4.x генератор инициализируется с дефолтным сидом. В современном дотнете эта проблема решена и получить 2 одинаковых рандома нереально.